# Is Access limited to a number of user that connect and run query on Database?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Is Access limited to a number of  user that connect and run query on Database ?

i have shared Access file that 50 users connect and run query on hem

```
(select.....update....insert....delete)
```

my program that connect to this access in in C# (WinForm)

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5367716/352101

Comment: Access no. the os (it's just file), possibly. 50 concurrent users and access hitting the same table, never mind the same record = baaad idea.

Comment: For 50 users, Access shouldn't even be considered. In my opinion it shouldn't be considered for any application, ever, for any reason.

Comment: @Ginosaji Don't confuse Access 2007 and later with the old JET db engine horror. 2007 introduced an all new storage engine that carried nothing over from JET. An Access DB is now near the Sqlite level in terms of performance and reliability... it's just that it's still an in-process engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Access database has a limit of 256 connections, but there is a limit of 64 connections per process in the database drivers.

Hope this below screen shot will help you. You can make the necessary modifications according to your needs.

[image]

You should prefer other Database like SQL Server for good performance.

FYI - Choosing edited record lets users use the database together but not work on the same record e.g a student at same time...

### **[Need a persistent connection to the back-end from each of the front-end workstations.  This can be done using a bound form which is always open or by keeping a recordset open at all times..](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performanceldblocking.htm)**

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the limit is higher, but as a practical matter, your limit is **one**.

You may have used more in the past, but if so, you were lucky. Access is an *in-process* database engine. That means it works best when the database is loaded in with the process that is accessing it, and that in turn means that if you have more than one query writing into the database at a time, especially into the same table, you are leaving yourself open for corruption. Maybe not today, maybe not tomorrow, but soon, and when you least expect it.

If you're sharing a database among that many users, it's time to look for an *host-process* database engine... a server. Examples include Sql Server (Express Edition is free, even for commercial use), PostGreSQL, Oracle, and others.